# How can I apply sorting on JSON response and find out the last value of the sorted result?

Tags: javascript, java, json, sorting, jmespath

I have JSON response with the following data.

```json
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":123,
   "result":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"name1",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            101,
            "pname1"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"name4",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            104,
            "pname4"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"name2",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            102,
            "pname2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"name5",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            105,
            "pname5"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"name3",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            103,
            "pname3"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using JMESExtractor to retrieve the JSON data using `result[-1].product_id[0]` to get the last value.

But I want the last value of the array after sorting it.

So, all 5 records needs to be sorted by `product_id` and then I need the last value of `product_id`.

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":123,
   "result":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"name1",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            101,
            "pname1"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"name2",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            102,
            "pname2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"name3",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            103,
            "pname3"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"name4",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            104,
            "pname4"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"name5",
         "ref":false,
         "product_id":[
            105,
            "pname5"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want the value of `product_id=105` after sorting.

Is there any way to apply two functions at the same time on the same JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

The result of [`sort_by`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#sort-by) returns an array, on which you can freely do any other projection or filtering that you require.

So based on your JSON data, the query

```
sort_by(result, &product_id[0])[-1]
```

will return the object you are looking for

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "name5",
  "ref": false,
  "product_id": [
    105,
    "pname5"
  ]
}
```

And so you can easily go further and add the bit you tested already: `. product_id[0]`, in order to only get the `product_id` you were looking for.

And, so

```
sort_by(result, &product_id[0])[-1].product_id[0]
```

will give you

```json
105
```

Comment: It is Working Properly now as per my requirement.

Thanks.